# Lambda group by query with count in mvc5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I am writing lambda query to get some details from table. I want to get count of each same records with `UserID` and `AssetId`.

My table structure is as follows.

```
UserID     AssetID      ProductName   ProductLocate
---------------------------------------------------
user1        as1           p1              c1
user1        as1           p2              c2
user1        as1           p3              c3
user2        as2           p4              c4
user2        as2           p5              c5
```

After querying I want data in the below form

```
UserID     AssetID      ProductName   ProductLocate Count
----------------------------------------------------------
user1        as1                                     3
user2        as2                                     2
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What language is to be used? Not much help can be provided without those details.

Comment: My code is not correct right now. I using C#.

Comment: if the format always look like this i would just use a joint key to group like `myList.GroupBy(o=> o.UserId + "-" + o.AssetID)`

Comment: And what about counting?

Comment: @Franck proper multiple keys should be done using an anonymous type, e.g. `myList.GroupBy(o => new { o.UserId, o.AssetID })`.

Comment: `table.GroupBy(r => new { r.UserID, r.AssetID }).Select(rg => new { rg.Key.UserID, rg.Key.AssetID, Count = rg.Count() })`